# Partial markup via Tapestry block

Tags: ajax, tapestry

I'm using Tapestry 5.3.

In a Tapestry component, I'm trying to implement an event handler that creates responses to AJAX requests.

I know that I can call `MarkupWriterFactory#newPartialMarkupWriter` to get an instance of `MarkupWriter` and then generate the response using this instance. The built-in mixin `Autocomplete` generates responses to AJAX requests in this way. Here is a trivial example:

```
@Inject
private MarkupWriterFactory markupWriterFactory;

@OnEvent("myevent")
Object generatePartialMarkup() {
    final ContentType contentType = new ContentType("text/html");
    final MarkupWriter markupWriter = markupWriterFactory.newPartialMarkupWriter(contentType);
    markupWriter.element("hr");
    markupWriter.end();
    return new TextStreamResponse(contentType.toString(), markupWriter.toString());
}
```

However, this is a clumsy solution for a partial HTML that is much more complex than just a `hr` element. I wonder if there is a chance to create such response using a Tapestry block rather than generating the response "manually" via `MarkupWriter`. If I just return an instance of block from the event handler, an exception is thrown when the event is triggered.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're making life difficult for yourself. From what I can see you can solve this with an `eventlink`, a `zone` and an event handler which returns a `Block`. See [here](http://tapestry.apache.org/ajax-and-zones.html) for more info.

Not entirely sure what you're doing but if you need to render a block as a string, see the capture component [here](http://t5stitch-lazan.rhcloud.com/capturedemo)

Comment: Thanks for your hints. I have avoided Tapestry zones intentionally in this case. First, Tapestry zones should not be nested (as far as I am concerned) and my Tapestry component with the handler is already used inside a zone. Second, the AJAX request is not fired by clicking an anchor but from the middle of a JavaScript function.

Comment: I made some stupid mistake during testing and implementing my handler. It already works today. It actually IS possible to return a block from event handler that produces response for an AJAX request. The resulting HTML markup is just wrapped in a JSON object (in contrast to using a MarkupWriter). ...sorry for a confusing question.